# How can I integrate the expansion pannel in redux pattern?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, ngrx, ngrx-store-4.0

> I'm using the `<mat-expansion-panel>` to define some
>   collapsible/expandable zones on the UI of a form component. The form
>   is integrated in redux with @ngrx/store, the problem is that if I use
>   [expanded] property on `<mat-expansion-panel>` the expansion panel
>   will be expanded but the animation is not triggered. Is this a bug  or
>   the expected behavior ?
>
> How can I integrate the expansion panel in @ngrx without breaking the
>   animations ?
>   [Here](https://github.com/nicolae536/ngt-configurable-form) is my repository

Answer (score 0):

> I managed to fix the problem using a directive

```
import { Directive, Optional, Input, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { MatExpansionPanel } from '@angular/material';

@Directive({selector: '[ngtExpansionPanelToggle]'})
export class ExpansionPanelToggleDirective {
    @Input()
    set isExpanded(state: boolean) {
        this.setIsExpanded(state);
    };

    @Output() onToggle: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    constructor(@Optional() private _matExpansionPanel: MatExpansionPanel) {
    }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    togglePanel(event) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.onToggle.emit(this.getExpandedState());
        }, 0);
    }

    private setIsExpanded(state: boolean) {
        if (!this._matExpansionPanel) {
            return;
        }

        let panelState = this._matExpansionPanel._getExpandedState();
        let newState = this.toPanelState(state);

        if (newState === panelState) {
            return;
        }

        this._matExpansionPanel.toggle();
    }

    private toPanelState(state: boolean) {
        return state
            ? 'expanded'
            : 'collapsed';
    }

    private getExpandedState(): boolean {
        let panelState = this._matExpansionPanel._getExpandedState()

        if (panelState === 'expanded') {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

> And I attached this directive to html like this

```
  <mat-expansion-panel>
                <mat-expansion-panel-header ngtExpansionPanelToggle
                                            [isExpanded]="rowConfig?.isPanelOpened"
                                            (onToggle)="handleTogglePanel(rowConfig, $event)">
                    <mat-panel-title class="ngt-group-title">
                        {{rowConfig.title}}
                    </mat-panel-title>
                    <mat-panel-description class="ngt-group-description">
                        {{rowConfig.description}}
                    </mat-panel-description>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                <ngt-form-elements *ngFor="let rowElements of rowConfig.elements"
                                   [formName]="formStaticConfig.name"
                                   [parentFormGroup]="ngFormGroup"
                                   [outsideDataProviders]="outsideDataProviders"
                                   [elements]="rowElements.elementsOnLine">
                </ngt-form-elements>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
```

> So if the panel state is updated using a browser event I will not
>   rerendere the view, otherwise will be rendered from configuration.